# Can't seem to target #document selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using embedly to embed a YouTube video on a page. When the iFrame is embedded, I'm attempting to target the video which is deeply nested within this iframe. I'm not sure how to target the #document so that I can continue to drill down (within its HTML tags) and find the actual embed of the video.

Is there a way to have jQuery find a specific class no matter how deeply nested it might be?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, you can't manipulate (or target in this case) anything inside an iFrame, for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to communicate with a document that's within an iFrame when the iFrame originates from a different domain.

See this article for more details:
http://madskristensen.net/post/iframe-cross-domain-javascript-calls

However, you'll likely be able to do what you need to do by using the YouTube JavaScript API:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference